# Executing bash script as root from a php script

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec, permission-denied

I have a command that can only be executed as root. I have put this command in a bash script called testscript. My testscript is placed at /home/$USER/. I want to execute this script using Php from a browser. I tried shell_exec but it gives me permission denied. How do i do this?